# Python one liner error ,when trying to read an write a file

Tags: python

here is my code :

```
with open('result2.txt', 'r') as file:filedata = file.read();filedata = filedata.replace('https://docs.google.com/viewer?', '');with open('result2.txt', 'w') as file:file.write(filedata);
```

and i have this error :

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax   File "", line 1
> with open('result2.txt', 'r') as file:filedata = file.read();filedata =
> filedata.replace('https://docs.google.com/viewer?', '');with
> open('result2.txt', 'w') as file:file.write(filedata);
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How to solve it ?

I can do a multi line program but by curiosity i would like to know the answer.

regards

Comment: `with open('result2.txt') as i_f, open('result2.txt', 'w') as o_f: o_f.write(i_f.read().replace('https://docs.google.com/viewer?', ''))`

Comment: Sorry, completely missed that you need to rewrite file. Correct option: `with open('result2.txt', 'r+') as f: s = f.read().replace('https://docs.google.com/viewer?', '') ; f.seek(0) ; f.write(s) ; f.truncate()`

Answer (score 0):

"However, this practice is not allowed if there is a nested block of statements."

You can't have nested blocks of code, your second file opening is nested.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-provide-multiple-statements-on-a-single-line-in-Python